# Writing a C++/CX wrapper class for native C++ class

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

Due to C++/CX classes not allowing native types in the public signature, I need to find an alternative way of getting the information in. I've found a couple of references to writing a wrapper class on the internet, but no actual implementations. How can I enable the following scenario in my code?

```
public ref class MyRefClass
{
public:
    void SetNativeType(NativeType *pType);
};
```

Obviously this won't work, so how do I wrap `NativeType` so that it can be passed into `MyRefClass`?

I should add that this is in a separate library, so the use of the `internal` keyword won't help here.

Comment: Does `SetNativeType` need to be public?  Could it be internal?

Comment: You'll need to have a wrapper class for each of your types. No way around it. Then in `SetNativeType` you can take the native type from the wrapper.

Comment: I think you should question who the consumer of MyRefClass is.  If you're trying to create a library to be consumed only by other C++ clients, you should consider making it a native DLL or static library instead of a WinRT component.  If it's meant to be a WinRT component, then the public surface should be useable from .NET and should contain no native types.

Comment: Cory - What does the wrapper look like?
@AndyRich - The consumer is is going to be multiple applications (the class itself derives from Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Page). I wanted to write 1 class which does all the UI for several of our apps. If I could have the option of "this library will only be used by a C++ project" then I'd turn that on. If I create a native DLL, can I still create a ref class type and use it from outside the library?

Comment: So are the consumers creating and handing off the `NativeType` to the RefClass? And are the consumers strictly native C++?

Comment: @Mark note that while you can create a WinRT component that works in C++/C#/JS, you can't use XAML UI components in an HTML app and can't use HTML UI components in a XAML UI app (unless hosting them in a WebView).

Comment: Yes, the consumer of the `Page` derived class would need to set the `NativeType` into the class. I think a static library might be best for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is enough just to wrap a pointer to your NativeType, you could use [Platform::IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755810.aspx) as a "generic" parameter.

From MSDN:

```
static IntPtr::operator IntPtr( void* value1);
static IntPtr::operator IntPtr( int value2);
static IntPtr::operator void*( IntPtr value3 );
```

As an alternative, you can have `SetNativeType(NativeType *pType);` as internal, and then distribute a static library with header files instead of a Windows Store class library.

About [the warning you mentioned in your comments](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/winappswithnativecode/thread/b9c8a6d0-d6e8-4300-ab04-ef42a332d92f), you could try having a plain C++ class MyPlainClass, and export its implementation instead in a lib file (even if you consume other ref classes inside), then provide a header-only ref class MyRefClass that wraps MyPlainClass and acts as a public interface. This solution is not perfect either, I am guessing you will have troubles combining in the same project two winrt libraries that use your lib+header files, but maybe you do not need to support this scenario.

Comment: I think static library might be the way to go. I hadn't realised that internal would work with a static library. Thanks.

Comment: It turns out authoring ref classes in static libraries isn't supported - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/winappswithnativecode/thread/b9c8a6d0-d6e8-4300-ab04-ef42a332d92f - although I could probably get it to work as I'm not concerned with their caveats (I don't need the type to be exposed from the final binary).

Answer (score 0):

Since WinRT (and COM) solves the very real problem of binary API compatibility, I've personally settled on using COM for this. You can declare a private interface without IDL or type libraries. All you need is to include the header with the interface declaration in the client. The matching IID and the interface signature is all you need (except to also figure out how to pass the IUnknown pointer).